# Rcpp_eval causes segfault when passing unevaluated arguments

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to evaluate variable inside Rcpp function

```
SEXP foo(SEXP arg) {
  SEXP x = NULL;
  try {
    x = Rcpp_eval(arg, Environment::global_env());
  } catch(...) {
    printf("Error\n");   
  }
  return x;
}
```

If `arg` is initialized in `.GlobalEnv` it seems fine.

```
x <- 1
foo(substitute(x))
```

But if `arg` is not initialized in `.GlobalEnv` segfault occurs

```
foo(substitute(y))
```

What am I doing wrong? Or it's a problem in `Rcpp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `x` to `R_NilValue` to return R's NULL on error, rather than a NULL pointer. Presumably you don't want to use `printf()` to handle the error. I guess you meant

```
x = Rcpp_eval(arg, Environment::global_env());
```

(`arg` rather than `mode`).

```
SEXP foo(SEXP arg) {
  SEXP x = R_NilValue;
  try {
    x = Rcpp_eval(arg, Environment::global_env());
  } catch(...) {
    printf("Error\n");
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not get it that error was in uninitialized return value.